# How can I hide a radio button using javascript in Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I have been using the following code to hide a radio button in a multiple choice, 3 column question in Qualtrics (so that option can be used like a sub head and cannot be selected). However the code has now stopped working with the new theme we are using.

```
$('QR~QID154~198').style.display='none';
```

The following code works to hide the radio dot, however it then right aligns all of the responses below it, so it won’t work.

```
$('QR~QID154~198').up().hide();
```

Any ideas on another way to code this in JS?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the buttons in a div and show or hide the div it is easier like that. you can also use .removeClass or .addClass with the div so it can be controlled from a script that would check if the class is there it will remove it or if it's not it will add it, you can use .hasClass to check weather it is there or not.